# How to interact with a REST api made with DRF

Tags: django, rest, react-native, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to use a REST api made with django REST framework to send data to my react native app. For authentification, I am using allauth which creates an authtoken when a user is created. My problem is: I don't know what to do next (once I have the token). I want to be able to retrieve my user's data with the API, but I don't know how to handle the authentification with DRF.

Do I have to send the token every time I make a request? If yes, what would the json would like? (frontend with react native)

How do I send the data back? Would it look like this:

```
def sendUsername(request):
    return request.user.get_username()
```

if not how? and if yes, it doesn't look very safe so is there a way to make it at least a little bit more secure?

I am really new to this so sorry if it looks dumb.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with DRF but without React, maybe I'll give you an idea of how to proceed

Backend
1.- Create an endpoint to log in
1.1.- Refresh user token
1.2.- Return user token
2.- Protect the api so it can not accept requests without token

Frontend
1.- Store the user token in the localStorage
2.- Make all request with user token

Optional:
If you need, you can create a Middleware to control the Authentication method

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to proceed in this case.
For one, you must have created an `authtoken/` url, that returns the auth token for the current user. You store the token within the browser. One place to store the token is in the `window.localStorage`.
While creating the rest APIs in django, you must have provided them different django permissions. So, for the ones whose permission is `AllowAny`, there is no need for authentication, but for the ones where the permission is `IsAuthenticated`, you have to send the token in the headers while doing any API request to the given API.

The decoding is based upon the kind of token. If you are using rest_framework_auth, in that case, the token decoding is done internally to realize the password for the user authentication. If you decide to go for jwt based authentication, you can write custom web authentication, which use jwt and sha1 algorithm to encode and decode the password respectively. If you want more details on jwt authentication, you can check out https://thinkster.io/tutorials/django-json-api/authentication.

The above method has its drawbacks, since anyone who gets access to your token can easily decode it, to find the password. Thus, a common practice is to use a salt as an additional factor to create the authtoken. Thus, after once encoding the given password, there is another encoding that happens with the salt, and this is then saved in the frontend. This ensures that the token that is present in the frontend can not be decoded by anyone who has the access to it and only by the ones who have access to the salt as well which is being stored for each user in the database.

The concept of salts comes into the picture when you are using the jwt authentication. There the password is saved as 'password+salt+shared_key', shared_key remains unique to the database while salt remains unique to the model field. This ensures that the password is difficult to crack. The above combination is then encoded through jwt.

Comment: I have a few questions: 1. How can someone get the password from the token? Is the token generated from the password? 2. Could you elaborate more on the salt because I can’t find anything about using a salt with drf on google?